# How to understand the unitary?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics

In the page 219 of Mahan's Many Particle Physics(3ed), there exists a transform 
$$ S=c^{\dagger}c\sum_q\frac{M_q}{\omega_q}(a_q^{\dagger}-a_q)$$
In order to prove that the transformation relating to $e^{S}$ is $\textit{unitary}$, we should prove that
$$(e^S)^{\dagger}(e^S)=I$$
or equivalently,
$$S^{\dagger}=-S$$

However, in my opinion,
$$ S^{\dagger}=\big(c^{\dagger}c\big)^{\dagger}\sum_q\frac{M_q}{\omega_q}(a_q^{\dagger}-a_q)^{\dagger}=\big(cc^{\dagger}\big)\sum_q\frac{M_q}{\omega_q}(a_q-a_q^{\dagger})=\big(-c^{\dagger}c\big)\sum_q\frac{M_q}{\omega_q}\big(-(a_q^{\dagger}-a_q)\big)=S$$
What's wrong?

Comment: In doing the hermitean conjugate of $c^\dagger c$ you forgot to revert the order.

Comment: Is $c$ a Grassmann-odd operator, and you are worried about the sign convention for Hermitian conjugate of Grassmann-odd operators?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is: $(AB)^\dagger=B^\dagger A^\dagger$. Look how you treat $c^\dagger c$.

Comment: Tks. I get it. I misunderstood $^{\dagger}$ as $^{T}$.

Comment: Tks. I get it. I misunderstood the algebraic properity of ${\dagger}$.

Comment: @Roger209: Please, be so kind and mark the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Ah, I have tried to upvote it. But I don't have the power. I will mark it in the future.

Comment: @Roger209: I meant mark as answer.